# Powershell Passing Funtion Varible for System.Net.DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell

Recently I have been working on trying to parse thru a series of servers for DNS information.  I can't seem to correctly pass the variable to the function.  Calling the function by itself and passing a variable works just fine.  What am I missing?  Please help.

```
Function Get-DnsEntry($computer)
{
 If($computer -match "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
  {
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($computer).HostName
  }
 ElseIf( $computer -match "^.*\.\.*")
   {[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($computer).AddressList[0].IPAddressToString}
ELSE { Throw "Specify either an IP V4 address or a hostname" }
    }

$computer = '"abc01.somenetwork.net"'
Get-DnsEntry $computer
```

So, of the above code, if i just run Get-DnsEntry "abc01.somenetwork.net" it works.  If I try to pass a variable to it as above, it fails find the host.

Comment: perhaps because you use single & doublequotes? `$computer = "abc01.somenetwork.net"` should work, tested with my own machine

Answer (score 3):

Please avoid using both single and double quotes, *e.g.* '"string"'

```
$computer = 'abc01.somenetwork.net'
Get-DnsEntry $computer
```

or

```
$computer = "abc01.somenetwork.net"
Get-DnsEntry $computer
```

Both should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, however that does not solve the issue.  I've tried a few variations of of the quotes, but none seem to resolve it.

Comment: @user2542412 What kind of error do you get while trying to do it with single quotes? What does `echo $computer` show?

Comment: With single quotes and double quotes, I get "Exception calling "GetHostEntry" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known""; The echo shows :     abc01.somenetwork.net     .   I was originally trying to add quotes with the variable to pass on.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to working....

```
Function Get-DnsEntry
{[cmdletbinding()]param([string]$computer)
 if($computer -match "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
 {
    [string]$hostname = $computer
    [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($hostname).HostName
 }
 elseif( $computer -match "^.*\.\.*")
 {
   [string]$hostname = $computer
   [Net.Dns]::resolve($hostname).AddressList[0].IPAddressToString
 } 
 else{ Throw "Specify either an IP V4 address or a hostname" }
}

 [string]$hostname = 'abc01.somenetwork.net'

 Get-DnsEntry $server -Verbose
```